# Losing reference to an element after opened dialog

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, reference

I am seeing odd behavior with element referencing:

I have a button that triggers mat-menu, which, in turn, opens a dialog. To get the focus back from the dialog to the original button, I pass the button as an element reference via @ViewChild to the component. After the dialog is closed (on subscribe) I attempt to refocus on the button but no action happens because the element is not in the DOM. If I manually query the button via document.getElementById() and then set the focus then everything works. I printed both versions and they seem the same but when compared via === they evaluate to false.

TS

```
@Component({
  ...
})
export class MyClass {
  @ViewChild('myButton', {read: ElementRef, static: false})
  myButton?: ElementRef;
  ...

  onButtonAction() {
    const myDialogRef = this.dialogRef.open(MyDialog);
    myDialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(() => {
      this.myButton?.nativeElement?.focus(); // doesn't work
      document.getElementById('myCoolButton')?.focus(); // works
    });
  }
```

HTML

```
<mat-menu #myMenu="matMenu">
    <button mat-menu-item
            (click)="onButtonAction()">
      Open dialog
    </button>
</mat-menu>
<button mat-icon-button
        type="button"
        id="myCoolButton"
        #myButton
        [matMenuTriggerFor]="myMenu"
        (click)="$event.stopPropagation()">
  <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
</button>
```

Why is this happening, and is there a better way to accomplish what I want.

Edit: It turns out this is happening due to re-rendering of the button. The component that holds the button and mat-menu gets reconstructed every time the dialog is opened. I currently have no way (and still looking for a way) to avoid this re-construct.

Comment: I'm not completely sure, but I guess that your button is been re-rendered when the `mat-menu` is opening and the reference is been changed as well. You could put a code break when the button's node is removed and take a look at the call stack trace to see what is making it to re-render

Comment: Is your dialog making any model updates? Look for `*ngFor` or `*ngIf` either in that component or up in the hierarchy. `*ngIf` temporary changing to false will destroy the current component. `*ngFor` iterating on a new object (immutable) will also create a new component (that can be fixed with adding [trackBy](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#ngForTrackBy)).

Comment: I do have multiple (necessary) ngIf's, which might be the problem. Does this mean the element cannot be passed by reference at all and I _have_ to query the element again?

Comment: The `*ngIf` wouldn't be a problem if it doesn't turn to _falsey_ temporarily.

Comment: My *ngIfs are based on observables, which can be falsey until the value is received

Comment: Btw if that helps I ran element1.isEqualNode(element2) for 'old' and 'new' buttons, and it returns true. element1.isSameNode(element2) returns false

Comment: Just checked that the component (with the button and the menu) get's reconstructed every time the dialog is opened. Is there a way to prevent it?

Comment: I think you should check why your component gets re-constructed it should boil down to a change in `*ngIf` or `*ngFor` up in the hierarchy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reference was lost due to reconstructing the component every time the dialog was opened. The whole row was re-rendered, and so adding trackBy to the rows solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this if you want to drop the subscription

```
const myDialogRef = this.dialogRef.open(MyDialog),{
   restoreFocus:true,
}
```